# Flask-SQLalchemy reset ids after deleting row

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table created according to the following model:

```
class Monitoring(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.String(150))
    match_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
```

I am able to delete specific rows by using:

```
@views.route('/home/delete', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_monitoring_entries():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form.get("delete_match_link"):
            Monitoring.query.filter_by(match_link=request.form.get("delete_match_link")).delete()
```

Currently, what the code does is deleting the row and keeping all the ids as they were before the specific row has been deleted.

However, after deleting any row, I would like the id column to be updated too so it always starts with 1 and increments for all the remaining rows.

I have tried to search for a way to do that but ended up not finding anything about how to achieve the expected result.

Comment: How to do this depends on the actual database being used.  But in general you shouldn't depend on specific ids existing, it will make your code very difficult to maintain.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I am using SQLite and honestly the table is just a temporary table that gets repopulated every day so I don't really need to reset the ids as it would start from 1 after all the entries are deleted or moved for the day, but I still get frustrated by the fact that all the ids displayed are all over the place while I would want to be able to know at any given time how many rows the table has and where in the table elements are